# Implementing variables with .actionPerformed in Java

Tags: java, swing, variables, actionlistener

I am by no means a programmer and have learned most of what I know by tinkering around on forums and looking through examples that are mostly written by you fine people. I have gotten to the point with java that I am trying to create buttons in a frame. Basically what I want to do is to read words from a file, create a button for each word, and then let me select that button to display options (that will be coded later). I know that this has been answered before, but none of the answers have really given me any clarification (again I am kinda a noob at this so non-programming jargon/simplistic explanation is greatly appreciated but of course not required :) ).

My code to create my variable buttons (desireFile is read from System in earlier in the program):

```
File fileIn = new File(desireFile);
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (fileIn);
int wordNum = 0;

while(fileReader.hasNext()){
    String wordReader = fileReader.next();
        buttonVal = new JButton (wordReader);
    buttonVal.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    buttonVal.setEnabled(true);
    contentPane.add(buttonVal, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    wordNum++;
}
```

Where I use wordNum just to ensure that my loop is incrementing correctly. Then I have my ButtonListener class:

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  ButtonListener() {
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println("You clicked the button");
  }
}
```

I get this to work, it creates my variable buttons and whenever I click on any one of those buttons it prints "You clicked the button" in the console. The issue I am having is, that isn't what I want it to do in the end. I need the action to be variable depending on results from the main class (example if the text in the file reads "this is a dog", I need the button for "this" to do something different than the button for "is"). Another problem is that, with the file input being variable each time, I don't know how I would set up if/else statements (since the word could literally be anything, thus the button anything, no?)

Again I am just enjoying programming as a hobby and appreciate all help, if you could dumb down any explanations for me (or give me links that do a good job of it) I would appreciate it. I have been fine with everything in Java up to this point but these buttons have me stumped. Thanks for the help gurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the text of the JButton in one of two ways, either from the ActionEvent's actionCommand property obtained via

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String buttonText = e.getActionCommand();
}
```

or via its getSource

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String buttonText = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
}
```

How you deal with the String returned will depend on what you want to do with it and how you determine what to do with what word. Will you have a dictionary to look up the word and then decide what to do? Hard to say given the info so far.

Comment: You the man! Why was it that every forum or book that I tried to read through it had some crazy explanation about making a variable final or creating weird looking loops? Is there a thumbs up button on this site, cause you sir get one ;) (or madam, no offense intended)

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the check to the left of the answer. You can also up-vote an answer (or down-vote it) by clicking on the triangles above and below the big number (here a 0) to the left of the answer.